# Compare Two Text Files with Split Text 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, text, strip

So I have two files.  One contains Old Stuff and the other contains different New Stuff.

Each text file has the same format:
Example_Students_Year_School_Date

I want to be able to compare the files, and understand whether it's the Date or the Students that increased.  Then I went to write the Date to its own text file and Students to its own text file.

So let's say 
OldText has: 
Example_54_1994_WoodCreek_201309 
Example_56_2009_Marshall_201408 
Example_20_2008_DennnMan_201309

NewText has: 
Example_54_1994_WoodCreek_201402
Example_59_2009_Marshall_201408

The first entry in NewText would be sent to DateText since the DATE is more recent and the 2nd entry in NewText would be sent to StudentText since the STUDENTS increased.  Nothing would be done with the third entry in OldText since it is not within NewText.

I currently have:

```
for OldRecord in StripOldList:
    OldSplitRec = OldRecord.split('_')
    value1 = OldSplitRec[1]
    value2 = OldSplitRec[2]
    value3 = OldSplitRec[3]
    value3 = OldSplitRec[4]
    value3 = OldSplitRec[5]

diffdict = {}
for SomeRec in DiffSplitText:
    key1, key2, key3, key4, key5= SomeRec.strip().split('_')
    FinalLabel = key1+"_"+key2+"_"+key3+"_"+key4+"_"key5+"_"+key6
    diffdict[key1,key2,key3,key4,key5.strip()] = FinalLabel

    IsNewEdition = True
    IsNewVersion =  True
    IsNewFileType = True

    if (value1 == key1 and value2 == key2):
       IsNewFileType = False

       if (value3 >= key3):
           IsNewEdition = False

       if (value5 >= key5):
           IsNewVersion = False
    if (IsNewFileType == True):
       print "No Match"
    elif (IsNewEdiion == True):
       print  "Found new edition"
       link1.write(SomeRec)
    elif (IsNewVersion == True):
       print "Found new version"
       link2.write(SomeRec)

.close() #closed all files
```

It only iterates the first entry and stops, but there are more than just one different file.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: some input example would help

Comment: So let's say OldText has:
Example_54_1994_WoodCreek_201309
Example_56_2009_Marshall_201408

NewText has:
Example_54_1994_WoodCreek_201402
Example_59_1994_Marshall_201408

The first entry in NewText would be sent to DateText since the date is more recent and the 2nd entry in NewText would be sent to StudentText since the size increased

Comment: better to add it to your question.

Comment: Check out the [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#module-difflib) module.

Comment: Will the difflib module work if the lines aren't matched up? The OldText file could have 1,000 entries; whereas, the NewText could have just like 50.  I just need it to understand if the Students or Date increased and then send it to the corresponding text file.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that i come up with:

```
value1 = [];
value2 = [];
value3 = [];
value4 = [];
value5 = [];

for OldRecord in StripOldList:
    OldSplitRec =  OldRecord.split('_')
    value1 += [OldSplitRec[0]]
    value2 += [OldSplitRec[1]]
    value3 += [OldSplitRec[2]]
    value4 += [OldSplitRec[3]]
    value5 += [OldSplitRec[4]]

for SomeRec in DiffSplitText:
    key1, key2, key3, key4, key5= SomeRec.split('_')

    for k in range(0,len(value1) ):
        if (value1[k] != key1 and value2[k] != key2):
            print "No Match"
        if (value3[k] < key3):
            print  "Found new edition"
            link1.write(SomeRec)
        if (value5[k] < key5):
            print "Found new version"
            link2.write(SomeRec)


.close() #close all files
```

Comment: I don't necessarily want it to compare it just to the first line.  I want it to cycle through all the files within the text file.  So LINE1's parsed information would cycle all through OldText's parsed information, then LINE2's parsed info would cycle all through OldText, then LINE3, etc.

So unfortunately I receive an output like:
Match! Good!
OLD: Example_54_1994_WoodCreek_201309 <br>
NEW: Example_54_1994_WoodCreek_201409  <br><br><br>

No Match
OLD REPEATED: Example_54_1994_WoodCreek_201309 <br>
Other File compared: Example_20_2008_DennnMan_201309  <br>

Comment: I had it very similar to yours before, but came to the same outcome I am now where it only does the first line entry, matches or doesn't match and then stops.  Eventually I read I could not loop through 2 text files which is why I went ahead and created them as a LIST and a DICTIONARY.

Comment: see my updated answer. the first loop reads all the information from the old file and stores it. the second for loop reads each line of the new file and compares it to all of the information from the old file. thats what the nested for loop within the second for loop is for. hopefully this is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at the UPDATE and will let you know!

Comment: I was able to fix it with a break and a .seek(0)